# Appengine Request Duration for Backend Services

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gae-backends

I am in the process of migrating an Appengine Java application from Backends to modules / services.  One thing that we currently use our backend for is uploads of data that take longer than the 60 second request duration limit.  So far, I have been unable to find a way to configure services to accept requests longer than 60 seconds without returning a CancellationException.  Surely Appengine did not drop support for longer requests with the conversion to services?  How can they be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please have a look at the following link

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/an-overview-of-app-engine

you need to configure your module as manual or basic scaling